# How to make jQuery UI elements react to HTML5 pointer events?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, pointer-events, handjs

I'm trying to 'marry' jQuery-UI functionality with the new HTML5 pointer events, but no luck so far. For example, how to make the [draggable sample](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#default) work with those events? Even high-level steps / direction answer would be appreciated.

I've tried the [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) — but it doesn't seem to support touch events on my laptop at all in any browser (Lenovo X1 Carbon Touch, Windows 8.1, IE 11, Chrome 30). I think it's targeting mobile platforms like iPad / iPhone, alas I need I need something that would work on a laptop as well.

Then I've tried [Heyman's Draggable Touch](https://github.com/heyman/jquery-draggable-touch) — it (mostly) works in Chrome, but not so much in IE; it is limited to support dragging, hence doesn't apply to, say, resizable elements; finally it doesn't use the pointer events from the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/) (instead it uses "touchstart" and other "tocuh*" events, so wouldn't react to a pen, and also those don't seem to be in any standard specification, or maybe I just can't find one).

Finally, I've tried [HandJS](http://handjs.codeplex.com/), which promises [cross-browser support for pointer events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/01/16/hand-js-a-polyfill-for-supporting-pointer-events-on-every-browser.aspx). I've added the script to my page, but it didn't enable touch drag for jQuery-UI draggable elements. Mouse dragging works, as always, but not touch. I'm referencing `jquery-2.0.3`, `jquery-ui-1.10.3` and `hand-1.2`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI supposedly has pointer event support built in now. I also wrote a gesture abstraction library so you do not need to care if the browser only has mouse, or does Apple's touch API or supports Pointer events at http://deeptissuejs.com. I have some updates coming in a few weeks so stay tuned!